# Word with the largest number of different phonetic vowel sounds

Tags: optimization, language, english

Which English word has the largest number of <strike>different</strike> unique phonetic vowel sounds in it?

I will only count one vowel sound per syllable.

To make it more like a competition, if two people get the same number of unique sounds, the winner  is the shorter word.  If that is equal too it is the first answer.

If there is a dispute about pronunciation and what is a proper word, I will take whatever the OED says as gospel.  Your word has to be in the OED to count.

No hyphens or spaces are allowed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Comment: @bobble On the other hand, there's a fixed finite number of vowel phonemes in English, so this is a bounded problem, with a clear upper bound and potentially a provable supremum.

Answer (score 9):

I have **7** in 15 letters:

> aerodynamically
>  â ō ī ā ĭ ə ē

Comment: Isn’t that 7, not 6?  This seems to be one of the best so far.

Comment: Wow, I can't count.  Changed it to 7.  Thanks!

Comment: One question is if there are two vowel sounds or one in the "cally" part. Is it pronounced as "clee"?

Comment: In British English "medically" is pronounced `mɛdᵻkli`.

Comment: I've seen it notated kali, kəli, k(ə)li, and kli in these types of words, and I'm honestly not sure which applies here.  I don't have access to OED to double check their preferred pronunciation

Comment: @TwoBitOperation The OED generally lists derived adverbs under their derivation base (_aerodynamic_ in this case) and doesn’t include pronunciation for derived terms unless unpredictable; there is no pronunciation available for _aerodynamically_. As Lembik points out, _medically_ does have its own entry (for some reason): its BrE pronunciation is /ˈmεdı̵kli/ with no schwa; the AmE one is /ˈmεdək(ə)li/ with a parenthesised one. So if you stick with the US pronunciation, the OED backs you up that there are at least potentially seven distinct vowels: [ε oʊ/ə aɪ æ ɪ (ə) i].

Comment: Pronouncing -cally seems to vary like pronouncing "the".  Seems to matter in the way the preceding words are said and the speed/rate.

Answer (score 8):

Probably not the most serious but...

> Jim Carrey pronouncing Beautiful Bee-ee-a-u-ti-full. The e is a repeat but the second u is different.
>  5 different sounds, 0 legitimacy as an answer.

Comment: Very nice indeed :)

Answer (score 6):

Taking a famously long word,

> antidisestablishmentarianism

has, I think, five (with apologies for crappy ad hoc notation):

> **a** **ee** **ih** **[schwa]** a ih [schwa] **eh** ee [schwa] ih

Incidentally, I think a better tie-breaking system would be to favour the *shortest* word with a given number of different vowel sounds. [EDITED to add: it turns out the OP thinks so too and has changed the question appropriately.]

Comment: You are right!  Changing it.

Comment: Does the c-word meet our quality standards? (As a nonnative speaker I am not always sure what is a "funny" expression, and what tends to be offensive).

Comment: Your word  might have more than 5  different vowel sounds, allowing for alternate pronunciations. [This companion word](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/floccinaucinihilipilification) seems to have 5, with one repeated 7(!) times in a row, free for the taking if you'd like

Comment: @Matsmath It wouldn't bother me to see it in someone else's answer, but if any reader indicates that they're offended by it then I'll happily change it.

Comment: @humn Yes, I thought about claiming 6 rather than 5 but thought I'd be modest.

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antidisestablishmentarianism) gives five for both UK and US pronunciations, but you could get more if you count /ɛ/, /ə/, and /ɛə/ as three different phonemes, or /ɛ/ and /ɛ:/.

Comment: @Matsmath: *crappy* is pretty innocuous — adds informality, but hardly anyone would view it as offensive today.  It took a long double-take to understand your comment, though, since *the c-word* usually refers to a different word which *is* still considered offensive in many contexts — probably currently the most offensive word in the language, in most English-speaking cultures.  If you’re not sure what word I mean, look up George Carlin’s *Seven dirty words*.

Comment: I would pronounce that first "i" "eye," which would add another sound.

Comment: @Devsman Only British people ever say antidisestablishmentarianism :)

Comment: @Lembik I didn't know anybody did. :)

Answer (score 5):

### Six

Another famously long word:

> floccinaucinihilipification.

Despite the surfeit of /ɪ/ sounds in here, there are actually **six** different vowel phonemes! At least with one of the two different possible pronunciations listed by [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/floccinaucinihilipilification):

> /ˌflɒksɪˌnɔːsɪˌnaɪhɪlɪˌpɪlɪfɪˈkeɪʃən/ has vowel sounds `ɒ, ɪ, ɔː, aɪ, eɪ, ə`.

Answer (score 5):

A word in the OED with 8 different vowel sounds:

> supercalifragilisticexpialidocious 
>  
>  suːpəkalɪfradʒɪlɪstɪkˌɛkspɪalɪˈdəʊʃəs

Comment: How do you count 8?  The vowels seem to be `u ə a ᵻ a ᵻ ɪ ɪ ɛ ɪa ᵻ əʊ ə`.  But I think `ɪa` is really two syllables and I don't know the difference between `ᵻ` and `ɪ`.

Comment: @Lembik: I make it 8 as follows: u, ə, a, ɪ ×2, ɛ, əʊ, ə.  Here the “ɪ ×2” is because the OED makes an odd choice in transcribing the i-vowels of “-istic” and “-expia-” as the same phoneme “ɪ” — they were historically the same, but for most speakers today they’re very different.  (For a shorter word illiustrating the contrast: these are the first and third vowels in *symposium.*)

Comment: I think you have counted `ə` twice. We are counting unique vowel sounds.

Comment: I get eight too, though not quite the same eight as the OED: [*uː ə a ɪ* a *ı̵* ɪ ɪ *ε i* a ɪ *əʊ*]. Note that the OED gives a _phonemic_ transcription: according to their view, /ı̵/ does not exist phonetically. It does for me, though: I have three phonetically distinct vowels in _Rose’s_, _Rosa’s_, and _sis_ (that is, my reduced /ɪ/ differs from both my non-reduced /ɪ/ and my /ə/ phonetically). They also don’t seem to have updated their IPA to reflect the change in writing ‘happy tensing’ /i/ as /i/ for this word. Since the question is about phonetic, not phonemic, vowels, I’d say 8 for this.

Answer (score 4):

**7 vowel sounds** (US pronunciation only): in **13 letters**:

> radioisotopic. The OED lists one US pronunciation as /ˌreɪdioʊˌaɪsəˈtɑpɪk/, with the 7 vowels /eɪ, i, oʊ, aɪ, ə, ɑ, ɪ/. The British pronunciation is only transcribed with 6 distinct vowels at most because the "i" in "radio-" is identified with /ɪ/.

**7 vowel sounds** (pretty solidly, I think) in **16 letters**:

> rhinolaryngology. The OED transcription is /ˌrʌɪnəʊˌlarᵻŋˈɡɒlədʒi/.

Since ["/ᵻ/" is equivalent to "/ɪ/ or /ə/"](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-pronunciation/), this means this word can potentially can be pronounced with the 7 distinct vowel sounds

> /ʌɪ, əʊ, a, ɪ, ɒ, ə, i/

Sources used:

> This is a minor variation of one of the words mentioned in the following article: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/what-is-the-longest-english-word (*otorhinolaryngological*)

**7 vowel sounds** (but I don't think they're all legitimately distinct) in **12 letters**:

> radiobiology. The OED transcribes this as /ˌreɪdɪəʊbʌɪˈɒlədʒi/, giving 7 distinct vowels: /eɪ, ɪ, əʊ, ʌɪ, ɒ, ə, i/. However, I think few people actually distinguish the sound of the "i" in "radio-" from the sound of the "y" in "biology." That's why I don't think this is legitimate.

**8 vowel sounds** (but I don't think they're all legitimately distinct) in **26 letters**:

> radioimmunoelectrophoresis (another word from that article). The OED transcription is /ˌreɪdɪəʊˌɪmjᵿnəʊᵻˌlɛktrə(ʊ)fəˈriːsɪs/.

Why I think it's not legitimate:

> As previously mentioned, the standard view, maintained by the OED, is "/ᵻ/" is just a notational shorthand for ""/ɪ/ or /ə/". So /eɪ, əʊ, (j)ᵿ, ᵻ, ɛ, ə, iː, ɪ/ does not constitute a set of 8 distinct vowels because /ᵻ/ is really the same as either /ɪ/ or /ə/. However, [Janus Bahs Jacquet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44409/word-with-the-largest-number-of-different-phonetic-vowel-sounds/44463#comment133584_44428) left a comment arguing that he does use three distinct vowels /ɪ/, /ə/ and /ᵻ/.

If we allow this, then I have another word with **7 vowel sounds** in **15 letters**:

> radiomicrometer: the OED transcribes the parts of this word separately, the prefix "radio-" as /ˈreɪdɪəʊ/ and "micrometer" as /mʌɪˈkrɒmᵻtə/

The 7 vowels are:

> /eɪ, ɪ, əʊ, ʌɪ, ɒ, ᵻ, ə/. I think this is a bit more legitimate since the first "/ɪ/" can actually be pronounced /i/, although the OED's transcription of British English does not acknowledge this.

Comment: What a great answer!

Answer (score 3):

I have **6 sounds** in **14 letters**. If you don't believe me, perhaps you are an

> underestimator

and if you don't like that word (since [it's not in the OED](http://public.oed.com/?post_type=page&s=underestimator)), you're still

> underestimating

EDIT: It appears I *overestimated* and have only 5 unique sounds.

Comment: By my count those have at most 5 each: in *underestimator*, the last syllable has the same vowel as the 2nd syllable, and in *underestimating*, the last syllable has the same vowel as the 4th syllable.  (And in some accents, the 4th syllable will be the same as the 2nd syllable — it gets reduced to a schwa as it’s completely unstressed.)

Answer (score 3):

I have 10 in a 20 letter word from http://www.yougowords.com/10-vowels word list. The word is Semiautobiographical, however, I think Semiautobiographical might need a dash to become Semi-autobiographical

Even au-to-bi-o-gra-phi-ca-l by itself is 7 phonetic sounds of vowels but I am horrendous at English. Thought I'd add to the list of answers just in case it's helpful list.

Comment: Are they unique vowel sounds?

Answer (score 2):

a quick guess,

> Disenfranchise disənˈfran(t)SHīz has 4 different vowel sounds. There are probably words with five but I can't think of any yet.

Answer (score 1):

six different vowel sounds in 12 letters

> on·o·mat·o·poe·ia

Comment: `ɒ ə a ə i ə`  I make that 4 different sounds.

Comment: @Lembik Question is not clear on on that to me

Comment: Why so? I just looked it up in the OED and copied out the vowel sounds in order.

Comment: I guess part of the puzzle is understand the question.    If I have 4 children and two are named Jim do I have 4 different children?

Comment: Aha... In my question I meant that that vowel sounds are different. So in your example it would be the names of the children that have to be different.  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is unique.

Comment: Question edited to use the word unique. Thank you!